# Call API from LWC OSS

Tags: node.js, lwc-oss, node-salesforce

I created an LWC OSS app with express server using npx create-lwc-app:

- **Do you want to use the simple setup?** Yes
- **Package name for npm** demo-app
- **Select the type of app you want to create** Standard web app
- **Do you want a basic Express API server?** Yes

[image]

I paste the component [miscRestApiCall](https://recipes.lwc.dev/#misc) from [reciepe](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes-oss/tree/main/src/modules/recipe/miscRestApiCall) in the client and the other elements needed (my own code repo here : https://github.com/jeremyvial/testcallapilwcoss) but when I try the API call, I got error in the fetch function ( https://testlwcframworkk.herokuapp.com/ ) linked to the CSP.

Any clue about how and where i can autorise the call in the context of express server ?

[image]

Comment: You need to set the CSP policy in your node JS application response header. Check [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-node-js-applications-with-a-content-security-policy) article.

Comment: @rahulgawale  I may update the wrong file but already did it reusing helmet module provided https://github.com/jeremyvial/testcallapilwcoss/blob/main/scripts/server.js

Comment: This is the correct file but as per the error message your policy has been ignored. I have never used `Helmet` so no Idea why is it being ignored.

Comment: Me neither, just reused the exemple script :) I will try without the helmet module. But as there is 2 server running (front hosting lwc and express hosting an api server) I'm affraid  I have some confusion between the 2 NodeJs server.

Comment: Are you performing the api call from the Server? or the Client? fyi: I copy pasted the code from the recipe, and everything ran without issue. I am performng the api call from the client (lwc js file).

Comment: @glls the request is run from the LWC component in the client server https://github.com/jeremyvial/testcallapilwcoss/blob/main/src/client/modules/my/miscRestApiCall/miscRestApiCall.js. The only change i made  with the recipe that work is create a project with Express Api server

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the problem. When I compare with the recepe script, I see that I uses helmet function in the wrong order [image]

EDIT : If you want call the webservice host by the back express server there is this great tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHD5VZVabNw